# Wrapping Windows Handles in a class

Tags: c++, windows

I'm writing a C++ framework so that I can rewrite some software to work on multiple platforms. The question I have pertains to an implementation of some wrapper classes that use Windows handles. Consider the following code...

```
class Font
{
public:
  Font(const LOGFONT& lf)
  {
    m_hFont = ::CreateFontIndirect(lf);
  }

  ~Font()
  {
     ::DeleteObject(m_hFont);
  }

private:
  HFONT m_hFont;
}
```

I then have a Display class where I might call the following...

```
LOGFONT lf;
// initialise lf

Display d;
d.SetFont(Font(lf));
d.DrawText(0,0,"Some Text");
```

The problem of course is that d.SetFont will result in the m_hFont being deleted by the Font class destructor. I appreciate that I could create the font on the heap and let the graphics class be responsible for the Font's overall "lifetime". I guess that this is really a design issue. Is it better to...

1. Implement reference counting for classes that wrap Windows Handles.
2. Create wrapper classes on the heap.
3. Some other method?

I notice that MFC has an explicit DeleteObject in their wrappers but this of course does not result in automatic resource de-allocation.

Any help/advice appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT: I think this is more of a copy constructor question. I.e. My Font class creates a Windows FONT handle, but is destroyed because I pass the Font object to the display by value.

Answer (score 2):

You have at least three options:

1. Mind "the rule of three": if a class has a non trivial destructor then it should probably also implement a copy constructor and an copy assignment operator. In this case, they should insure that every copy has its own version of a `m_hFont`.
2. Use reference counting.
3. Change `Display::SetFont` to accept a pointer to a `Font` or a const reference. That way you can still create the `Font` "on the stack" and, if you only pass a pointer or a reference to it there will be no copies being made.

EDIT

1. You might be able to avoid the problem entirely if you make `Display::SetFont` accept a `LOGFONT` directly. This way, the `Display` class itself will manage the fonts (e.g. delete the old font structure and create the new). This option works best if you plan to use the `Font` object only in the context above (with a `Display`) and if the font changes are few.
2. Make the `Font` class also hold the `LOGFONT` as a member and generate the HFONT only on demand. When copied, the `LOGFONT` will be copied and the `HFONT` be given an invalid value. If the new `Font::GetFont` is called (say by the `Display`) then the `HFONT` will be created. In the Font destructor, if the `HFONT` is not the invalid value delete it. This will avoid some unnecessary calls to `CreateFontIndirect` if not all the copies will be used to call `GetFont`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm actually thinking it might it better to pass the Font object to a method rather than the display holding a reference. For example, I have a method, DrawText(int x, int y, const String& text). Might be better if I made this DrawText(int x, int y, const String& text, const Font& font).
Failing that, reference counting like you say is the way to go. Not sure how I reference count windows handles though, roll my own class?

Comment: @Karl It depends on how often you need to change the `Font`. If every `DrawText` might use a different `Font` then yes, make it a parameter. Otherwise, it is better to have a separate `SetFont` method. I will add an option 4 to my answer.

Comment: Thanks Andrei. I prefer the option of the Display class having a default font style. This takes the onus away from the library user. The default font can then obviously be changed by calling SetFont. The problem is that by passing the Font by value the Windows handle is destroyed by the Font destructor. I guess for this scenario that reference counting is the way to go. This is initially what I thought but just wanted other opinions :-)

Comment: Excellent! Point 2 makes a lot of sense. Using a LOGFONT will ensure that the default copy constructor works ok as LOGFONT is only a structure (member-wise copy will suffice). Not sure how this will fit in with other classes I need to create (pen, Brush, etc) but is a great starting point. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: @Karl you still need to add copy and assignment constructors (to make sure the copy has an invalid HFONT -- or an isValid flag is set to `false`).

Comment: Agreed. I will also add a CreateFont method to my font class that will return the actual HFONT handle for use by my display class. Of course that means my display class is responsible for HFONT lifetime management. Not ideal, as I think the font class should be responsible for this. But it's a workable solution.

Comment: @Karl, No, the `Font` object holds a `LOGFONT`, a `HFONT` and an `isValid` flag (if there is no suitable invalid value for the `HFONT`). This class will still be responsible for resource management, `GetFont` will return a pointer/reference to the internal `HFONT` if `isValid` is `true` or it will create the `HFONT` and set `isValid` to `true`. The copy c'tors will only copy the `LOGFONT` and set the copy's `isValid` flag to `false`.

Comment: Ah right, I get what you mean now, I think. So I create a new font, by passing in a LOGFONT. This destroys/overwrites the existing LOGFONT and HFONT and sets a valid flag as appropriate. I can create the HFONT when suitable parameters are passed to the create method and set the valid flag to true/false as appropriate. Still suffers from the original problem though, invoking the copy constructor will destroy the HFONT. As I see it , the only way around this is to get the HFONT on demand, e.g. HFONT hFont = myFont.CreateFont();

Comment: @Karl "The copy c'tors will only copy the LOGFONT and set the copy's isValid flag to false". Try writing all the workflow on paper.

Comment: Thanks Andrei, I will try that. Thanks also for your help, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That's the nature of Windows.  When you use resources in such a way like calling CreateFontIndirect, you'd have have to call DeleteObject or a method of some sort to release resources when you're done.  What exactly is the problem? Is your program not behaving as expected?  It should be fine unless lf goes out of scope before you use it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I appreciate that, but I want to automatically release resources in the class destructor. The problem is that calling d.SetFont(Font(lf)) eventually invokes the Font's class destructor making the FONT handle useless for the display class. I guess this is because I create the font on the stack.

Comment: It seems that you're passing the Font object by value, so your Display instance gets a copy of it.  The Font object you passed gets created and destroyed, but Display has a copy of it.  You're program should still be working ok. I'm only judging from the code you've provided.

Comment: Agreed, so in my copy constructor do I re-create the font handle. As you rightly suggest, the Font object is passed by value so is destroyed and I lose the Windows handle.

Comment: From the way your class is set up, yes.  You need to have  m_hFont = ::CreateFontIndirect(lf); in all constructors.

Comment: Excellent, sounds simple enough :-)
I'm new to the site, how do I vote for your answer?

Comment: I don't think you have enough reputation to vote.  Anyway, just to state the obvious.  The way you're passing the Font object isn't efficient.  You're creating and destroying every time you pass it to a function.  Perhaps try a different approach like instantiating font in Display or passing a reference to a Font.

Answer (score 0):

Following advice from the answers and some further thought I have adopted the following approach. I think that the Display class should manage the font's lifetime. Library users would supply font settings to the display class. Basic code is as follows...

```
struct Typeface
{
   bool Bold;
   int Width;
   int Height;    
};

class Font
{
public:
  Font();
  ~Font();  // calls DeleteObject(m_hFont)

  HFONT Handle() const { return m_hFont; }

  // Create will destroy the current font handle and create a new one
  void Create(const Typeface & tc);

private:
  HFONT m_hFont;
};

class Display
{
public:
  // select font modifies the display's current font
  void SelectFont(const Typeface& tf);

  // Draw a string using the display's selected font
  void DrawString(int x, int y, const String& text);

  // Draw a string using the supplied font
  void DrawString(int x, int y, const String& text, const Font& font);

private:
  Font m_hSelectedFont;  // Font handle automatically destroyed
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the most convenient solution in C++20:

```
using XHFONT = unique_ptr<remove_reference_t<decltype(*HFONT())>, decltype([]( HFONT hf ) { hf && DeleteObject( hf ); })>;
```

unique_ptr<> can only manage data for pointers, but fortunately Windows hanlde are always pointers, usually declared with DECLARE_HANDLE, and you can declare wrappers for any Windows hanlde type except HANDLE because a HANDLE is simply a void-pointer where remove_reference_t<decltype(*HFONT())> doesn't work.